# SAXParseException: cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'true' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'

Tags: java, soap, xsd

I am working on a java project that generates classes from XSD files
and I am using **jaxb2-maven-plugin** for that purpose

I have a XSD file that imports the following schema

`<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`

and there is an error when running that plugin

```
SAXParseException: cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'true' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '0|1' for type '#AnonType_mustUnderstand'.
```

any idea?

I have to use SOAP 1.1 and it seems the issue is related to the pattern defined in that attribute

`<xs:attribute name="mustUnderstand">   <xs:simpleType>     <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean">       <xs:pattern value="0|1"/>     </xs:restriction>   </xs:simpleType> </xs:attribute>`

I tried to copy that imported schema and remove the pattern inside the attribute "mustUnderstand" or find another plugin